# Do these simple python functions I've made have a bug?

Tags: python

I am currently testing some functions. Something seems off, but I simply cant figure out what.

There are 2 lists, guess list `a`, and pre-set list `b`. I want to check if a specific member of the `a` list is:

1. Existing in `b` list and matches the `b` member of the same index
   (OnPlace)
2. Does not exist at all in `b` list(NonePlace)
3. Exists in `b` list however the indexes of the matching members are
   not the same(OffPlace)

The code is below.

Two things to note:

- Only integers from 1 to 6 will be the members of both lists in the program.
- The len of the lists is capped to 4.

https://hastebin.com/odilafikoy.yaml

```
a = [1,4,5,6]
b = [1,6,1,1]

# Guess List is x parameter, index is y parameter

def OnPlace(x,y):
    global b
    if x[y] == b[y]:
        return True

def NonePlace(x,y): 
    global b
    if x[y] != b[1] and x[y] != b[2] and x[y] != b[3] and x[y] != b[0]:
        return True

def OffPlace(x,y):
    global b
    if x[y] != b[y]:
        if y == 0:
          if x[y] == b[1] or x[y] == b[2] or x[y] == b[3]:
             return True
        if y == 1:
           if x[y] == b[0] or x[y] == b[2] or x[y] == b[3]:
              return True
        if y == 2:
           if x[y] == b[1] or x[y] == b[0] or x[y] == b[3]:
             return True
        if y == 3:
           if x[y] == b[0] or x[y] == b[2] or x[y] == b[1]:
              return True
              
              
print(OnPlace(a,0))
print(NonePlace(a,2))
print(OffPlace(a,3))
```

Comment: I'm confused are you asking people to debug your code for you? 
It may be advantageous for you to write tests for your software and maybe come back if you have a specific and solavble issue

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified like this, and will be much easier to understand whats going on

```
a = [1,4,5,6]
b = [1,6,3,1]
#Guess List is x parameter, index is y parameter
def OnPlace(x,y):
    if x[y] == b[y]:
        return True
    return False
def NonePlace(x,y): 
    if x[y] not in b:
        return True
    return False
def OffPlace(x,y):
    if x[y] in b and b.index(x[y]) != y:
        return True
    return False
                          
print(OnPlace(a,1))
print(NonePlace(a,3))
print(OffPlace(a,2))
```

you don't need to use global keyword to access variables here, [check this out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/)

to know more about lists index function, [have a look at this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-index/)